# Tool for Library Dependency

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, solaris, ldd, nm

I'm looking for the `tool`/`command` on `Unix` platform to detect the `library` dependencies of the `.so` and `.o` files.

I have already used the `ldd`/`nm`/`truss`, but I don't know the proper approach to detect library dependencies.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what exactly is meant by "detect library dependencies".

The [`ldd`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) command works on shared libraries, not just on executables. It will display the dependencies of a shared library declared when the library was built:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff8fff000)
    libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f43fcf47000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f43fcd43000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f43fcb36000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f43fc7fc000)
...
```

A library can have undefined symbols that are obtained by linking with further libraries not declared as dependencies. You can use [`objdump -T`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump) or [`nm -D`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) to show the dynamic symbols - undefined symbols (those that should come from other libraries) will show up as `*UND*`:

```
$ objdump -T /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so | head

/usr/lib/libgtk-3.so:     file format elf64-x86-64

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000066e38 l    d  .init  0000000000000000              .init
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_param_spec_object
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_utf8_validate
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_date_get_month
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_bookmark_file_get_visited
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000              g_value_get_float
```

From these symbol names it should be possible to deduce undeclared library dependencies.

Libraries that use [`pkg-config`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkg-config) or similar configuration mechanism sometimes fail to declare their dependencies at build-time, but declare the dependencies to `pkg-config`, relying on the library users to use the tool to get the dependencies. `pkg-config --libs` will list the dependencies in the format understood by the compiler:

```
$ pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
-lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Comment: bravo! well explained. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks!!! Well explained, I just need a few more information about the usage of truss and nm.