# Is the ICU library corrupted?

Tags: unix, shared-libraries, icu, solaris-10, nm

I am getting the following output for the `nm –u` for a ICU library. Does it mean this library is corrupted? While using this library some of our code take 20 mins to complete the execution. I'm suspecting it is because of this library is corrupted but I'm not sure about it.

```
nm -u libicuuc.so.36

Undefined symbols from libicuuc.so.36:

    .div
    .mul
    .rem
    .stret4
    .udiv
    .umul
    .urem
    __1c2k6Fpv_v_
    __1cG__CrunKpure_error6F_v_
    __1cG__CrunKvector_con6FpvIIpF1_vp2_v_
    __1cG__CrunKvector_del6FpvIpF1_v_1_
    __1cG__CrunKvector_des6FpvIIpF1_v_v_
    __1cG__CrunKvector_new6FpvIIpF1_vp2_1_
    __1cG__CrunMex_rethrow_q6F_v_
    __1cG__CrunVdo_exit_code_in_range6Fpv1_v_
    __1cH__CimplKcplus_fini6F_v_
    __1cH__CimplKcplus_init6F_v_
    __ctype
    __udiv64
    __urem64
    _ex_deregister
    _ex_register
    _get_exit_frame_monitor
    atexit
    atol
    close
    fmod
    free
    getenv
    icudt36_dat
    log
    malloc
    mbstowcs
    memcmp
    memcpy
    memmove
    memset
    mmap
    modf
    munmap
    nl_langinfo
    open
    pow
    pthread_mutex_destroy
    pthread_mutex_init
    pthread_mutex_lock
    pthread_mutex_unlock
    realloc
    setlocale
    sprintf
    stat
    strcat
    strchr
    strcmp
    strcpy
    strlen
    strncat
    strncmp
    strncpy
    strrchr
    strstr
    strtod
    strtol
    strtoul
    time
    timezone
    tzname
    tzset
    wcstombs
```

Comment: no, its not corrupt. It just means that libicuuc.so.36 is referencing functions that aren't included in the .so file. You need to link other .so or .a files that DO contain those functions to have a working program.  The answer you received for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500658/tool-for-library-dependency/13502525 is a good place to start with figuring it out, or do more research about `make` based tool-chains. Good luck.

Comment: Also, 3.6 was released some time ago, perhaps try a newer version?